# Optocoupler drives a transistor - optocoupler doesn't turn off

Tags: opto-isolator, dali

[image: current limiter]

[image: DALI interface]

This is the circuit which comes from Microchip DALI example app note http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01465A.pdf

Here's the deal. Everything works as expected, if this circuit is powered with 9V. In my circuit, I use HCPL-181 type instead of TCLT1000, but the parameters are almost the same (including collector dark current). For debugging, I simply put 5V on the R5 resistor to drive the U1 optocoupler's LED.

If I increase the supply voltage to 11V or more, optocoupler U1 works properly if the voltage on its LED is present only for short time (0.5 s give or take). If I power the LED longer, optocoupler U1 fails to turn off. I also tried changing the value of R8 to 330R, to sink the current more effectively. Also I tried replacing the optocoupler, just in case. No effect. What could cause this?

Comment: What is connected to the DALI TX, DALI RX, and DALI BUS wires in your tests?

Comment: I agree with @ThePhoton - only half the story is given.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, you're driving your DALI bus from a voltage source, despite the power supply circuit which you've included. This causes Q2 to overheat (and maybe die). Try building the power supply circuit shown, and see if that doesn't help.

If you have built the power circuit as shown, why are you driving it with 9 volts, anyways?